# Hacer mi codigo pero ahora con clases

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo referente a un juego famoso que es el ahorcado, simplemente tiene tres dificultades que lo  hice con el switch, el do que esta encerrando todo para que el usuario se saliera con el numero 0 o si quisiera resolver otra palabra, y ya.
Solo que ahora me pidieron hacer este mismo codigo, pero adaptarlo con clases, y realmente nose hacer nada de eso, nunca he usado una en mi vida, se que se ponen como variables, y tienen sus metodos aritmeticos que resuelven lo que le pones, y se invocan con el nombre de la clase, un punto y el metodo, pero nose adaptarlo con esta actividad del ahorcado, fue una actividad que me costo bastante y con clases, menos sabre hacerlo, ayuda:(

````
public class AhorcadoMaximo{

public static BufferedReader entrada =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  private static final char CARACTER_PARA_SALIR = '0';
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {


Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    int clave;

boolean usuarioQuiereSalir = false;
       System.out.println("Elige la dificultad= 1)Facil 2)Normal 3)Dificil");
        clave=Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
        switch(clave){
           case 1:
          System.out.println("Estas en la dificultad facil");
               do {
            String[] palabras = {"agua", "aire", "papa", "loco", "wifi", "tela"};
            int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
            String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

            char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
            char[] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                sustitucionaterisco[i] = '*';
            }
            System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);


            boolean ganar = false;
            System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
            while (!ganar) {
                char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                    if (letras[i] == letraAdivinar) {
                        sustitucionaterisco[i] = letraAdivinar;

                    }
                }
                if (Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)) {
                    ganar = true;
                    System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
                }
                System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
            }
            System.out.println("Para salir escriba 0 y de enter, para continuar escriba cualquier otra opción");
            char continuar = lectura.next().charAt(0);
            if(CARACTER_PARA_SALIR==continuar){
                usuarioQuiereSalir = true;
            }
        }while (!usuarioQuiereSalir);
        break;

                   case 2:
         System.out.println("Estas en la dificultad normal");
                       do {
            String[] palabras = {"fabricas", "cachorro", "jabonear", "asaderas"};
            int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
            String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

            char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
            char[] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                sustitucionaterisco[i] = '*';
            }
            System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);


            boolean ganar = false;
            System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
            while (!ganar) {
                char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                    if (letras[i] == letraAdivinar) {
                        sustitucionaterisco[i] = letraAdivinar;

                    }
                }
                if (Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)) {
                    ganar = true;
                    System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
                }
                System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
            }
            System.out.println("Para salir escriba 0 y de enter, para continuar escriba cualquier otra opción");
            char continuar = lectura.next().charAt(0);
            if(CARACTER_PARA_SALIR==continuar){
                usuarioQuiereSalir = true;
            }
        }while (!usuarioQuiereSalir);
        break;
                   case 3:
        System.out.println("Estas en la dificultad dificil");
                       do {
            String[] palabras = {"alimentacion", "incredulidad", "ultramarinos", "secundiflora"};
            int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
            String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

            char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
            char[] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                sustitucionaterisco[i] = '*';
            }
            System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);


            boolean ganar = false;
            System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
            while (!ganar) {
                char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                    if (letras[i] == letraAdivinar) {
                        sustitucionaterisco[i] = letraAdivinar;

                    }
                }
                if (Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)) {
                    ganar = true;
                    System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
                }
                System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
            }
            System.out.println("Para salir escriba 0 y de enter, para continuar escriba cualquier otra opción");
            char continuar = lectura.next().charAt(0);
            if(CARACTER_PARA_SALIR==continuar){
                usuarioQuiereSalir = true;
            }
        }while (!usuarioQuiereSalir);
        break;
    }
}
} ```
````

Comment: Tu pregunta se me hace algo rara, dado que ya estás usando una clase para crear el juego; supongo que querrás decir con programación orientada a objetos. Sinceramente, siento que estás pidiendo que te hagan el ejercicio y eso va a ser complicado; lo meor que puedes hacer es estudiar un poco sobre cómo se implementan los objetos en java y preguntarle las dudas a tu profesor/a. Por si te sirve de algo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coK4jM5wvko&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk

Comment: hola máximo, mira no se si te pidieron un mínimo de clases pero yo separaría tu código en 2 que tendrías una clase llamada menú y otra que seria dificultades donde tendrías todo en métodos y después solo llamarías tus dificultades a tus CASES del menu

Comment: Está claro que nadie nace sabiendo. Tendrás que buscar algún manual de java y aprender sobre clases. Pretender hacer un programa sin tener idea del lenguaje es realmente complicado.